# mysql cluster with 1 master 1 node and 2 slave

Tags: clustering, mysql-5.7, ubuntu, master-slave-replication

My Query is I want to set up MySQL cluster with 1 Master 1 Node and 2 Slave with Auto failover. If my master is down node should assign slave as a master.

Can anyone suggest me an idea to do that? As I did research But I couldn't find any link for the same.

Comment: Check proxysql.  Or do a job that checks if the master is working as expected and if not promote a slave.

Comment: Can you suggest me a link to do the same? Because I tried to find the link for the same but I couldn't @ninjabber

Comment: https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/LATEST/index.html